# MySQL Workbench for Heroku/ClearDB - login problems?

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench

I have my clearDB username and password from Heroku. I also have the URL to connect to the database by using:

```
heroku config --app myappname
```

I have set up a connection using MySQL Workbench, and if I test the connection using the username and password that I got from Heroku it connects successfully.
However if I try to run ANY SQL command, such as:

```
CREATE DATABASE MY_DATABASE_NAME;
```

I get the following error

```
Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'myherokuusername'@'%' to database 'MY_DATABASE_NAME'
```

Normally I would expect

'myherokuusername'@'%'

to say

'myherokuusername@localhost'

which is possibly the source of the problem. However I can't see anywhere to set that user "myherokuusername" is @localhost?

Has anyone had this before or have any idea what the solution would be? I'm not particularly experienced with MySQl, I can run basic queries etc but the admin side of it I'm not too familiar with so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a general problem with our heroku app that day. Tried again the next day and mySQL was working as it should. If anyone has the same issue it may be worth waiting a day and trying again, if you can afford to.